# How do I delete all CKRecords for every type in default CKRecordZone?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Is it possible to do it with one request? I would like to avoid fetching every one separately and the perform deletion by record.

I know it is possible by deleting CKRecordZone unless zone is not default:)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the recordIDs of the records you wish to delete, you can call CKModifyRecordsOperation with the array of recordIDs to delete.

Alternatively you could setup all your records in the default zone to have one master reference record and each record set with this reference and a reference action of .deleteSelf.  To delete everything just delete the master reference record.

Comment: No, I do not have an ids... :(